# How can i clear the MUC history in Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have an application with chatting functionality which support group chat also. In my app i have many public groups, now i want to clear the MUC history of an existing public group without destroy that group.

Actually this group have many users and i don't want to miss anyone of them and i can't be force to anyone of them to join this group again.

I can try history_size: 0 but the problem for this is, group history will never come and that is not my requirement. I just want to clear group history once.

I have read on a link that Ejabberd doesn't provide any method for the room admins to clean the message queue. Is this true?

Comment: Do you have MAM enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to clean history, you should develop and add a new command in MUC admin API: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/ejabberdctl/muc-admin/